# break multicolumn into a whole line in toc

Tags: table-of-contents, multicol

#### Hello there

Im workin on an latex file where the `toc` is displayed in a `multicols` environment, there is a custom "part-like" element called `sobpart` that i want to break the two columns to display its line in a single column, this is what i have currently

````tex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{multicol}

% % Redefinition of ```\theHpart```
% \renewcommand\theHpart{\theHsobpart.\arabic{part}}

% sobpart
\newcounter{sobpart}
\renewcommand\thesobpart{\Roman{sobpart}}
\newcommand\sobpart[1]{
    % reset inner counter
    \setcounter{part}{0}
    \setcounter{section}{0}
    \setcounter{subsection}{0}
    \setcounter{subsubsection}{0}
    % add sobpart line
    \refstepcounter{sobpart}
    \part*{\thesobpart\hspace{1em}--\hspace{1em}#1}
%    % add to toc (old)
%    \addcontentsline{toc}{part}{
%         \end{multicols}  %% PW wrong place, see above
%        % \begin{multicols}{2}  %% PW wrong place, see below
%            \thesobpart\hspace{1em}--\hspace{1em}#1
%        % ]
%    }
    % add to toc (Peter's suggestion)
    \addtocontents{toc}{\end{multicols}}
    \addcontentsline{toc}{part}{\thesobpart\hspace{1em}--\hspace{1em}#1}
    \addtocontents{toc}{\begin{multicols}{2}}
}

\begin{document}


% Table of Contents
\renewcommand{\contentsname}{} % remove title

\begin{multicols}{2}[\section*{Content}]
    \tableofcontents
\end{multicols}

\part{part0.1}

\sobpart{sobpart1}

\part{part1.1}

\end{document}
````

---

###### add to toc (old)

my idea was to insert an `end/begin` `multicols` but whenever i comment out that modification i get the following error

```tex
./.build/test.toc:2: Missing } inserted.
<inserted text> 
}
l.2 ... I\hspace {1em}--\hspace {1em}sobpart1 ] }{1}
                                                  {}%
./.build/test.toc:2: Extra }, or forgotten \endgroup.
\l@part ...umwidth {\hss #2\kern -\p@ \kern \p@ }}
                                                  \par \nobreak \if@compatib...
l.2 ... I\hspace {1em}--\hspace {1em}sobpart1 ] }{1}
                                                  {}%
)
./test.tex:33: Missing } inserted.
<inserted text> 
}
l.33     \tableofcontents
                       
./test.tex:34: Extra }, or forgotten \endgroup.
\endmulticols ...le@items \color@endgroup \egroup 
                                                  \balance@columns \return@n...
l.34 \end{multicols}
```

---

##### edit 1: Redefinition of `\theHpart`

When trying to modify `theHpart` the following error occurs

```tex
./test.tex:6: LaTeX Error: Command \theHpart undefined.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              
                                                  
l.6 \renewcommand\theHpart
                        {\theHsobpart.\arabic{part}}
```

---

- edit 1: added Peter's suggestion and suggestion of redefinition of `theHpart` command

Answer (score 1):

You have the `multicols` environment codes added to the ToC in the wrong place.

```
% multicoltocprob.tex  SE 622645

\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{multicol}

% sobpart
\newcounter{sobpart}
\renewcommand\thesobpart{\Roman{sobpart}}
\newcommand\sobpart[1]{
    % reset inner counter
    \setcounter{part}{0}
    \setcounter{section}{0}
    \setcounter{subsection}{0}
    \setcounter{subsubsection}{0}
    % add sobpart line
    \refstepcounter{sobpart}
    \part*{\thesobpart\hspace{1em}--\hspace{1em}#1}
    % add to toc
    \addtocontents{toc}{\end{multicols}}
    \addcontentsline{toc}{part}{
%         \end{multicols}  %% PW wrong place, see above
        % \begin{multicols}{2}  %% PW wrong place, see below
            \thesobpart\hspace{1em}--\hspace{1em}#1
        % ]
    }
    \addtocontents{toc}{\begin{multicols}{2}}
}

\begin{document}

% Table of Contents
\renewcommand{\contentsname}{} % remove title

\begin{multicols}{2}[\section*{Content}]
    \tableofcontents
\end{multicols}

\part{part0.1}

\sobpart{sobpart1}

\part{part1.1}

\end{document}
```

However, for some reason the second `\part` is not appearing in the ToC. I'll leave that to you, or someone else, to sort out.

[image]

**EDIT** added *.toc file

```
\contentsline {part}{I\hspace {1em}part0.1}{1}{}%
\end {multicols}
\contentsline {part}{ I\hspace {1em}--\hspace {1em}sobpart1 }{1}{}%
\begin {multicols}{2}
\contentsline {part}{I\hspace {1em}part1.1}{1}{}%
```

Comment: Thats a good start, i believe that the ```\theHpart``` command must be modified, so that it includes the ```sobpart``` counter, i've tried to modify with the following command: ```\renewcommand\theHpart{\theHsobpart.\arabic{part}}``` but get the undefined ```\theHpart``` error